# preg_match - invalid range - very strange bug

Tags: php, regex

The code is this:

```
$k = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9ßöäüÖÄÜ\"\._-\p{L}]/u', '', $k);
```

(Yes I know it's redundant)
The error message:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 33
```

Now look at this line, it works fine:

```
$k= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9ßöäüÖÄÜ\"\.-_-\p{L}]/u', '', $k);
```

So adding or removing one "-" in the regex makes a huge change.
Both regex lines work when removing the\p{L}

Is that a bug in PHP (5.6.30) or did I miss something essential ? (it's 7 am here and I need sleep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a character class, a character range is defined with the character `-` (hyphen), but `_-\p{L}` doesn't define a range.

To figure a literal hyphen in a character class you have several possibilities in PHP:

- escape it with a backslash
- put it at the start of the class or after the negation character `^`
- put it at the end of the class
- put it after a range or a shorthand character class.

This last one isn't well known and is the cause of your strange result. In the second pattern, you are in this situation:

```
   .-_    -     \p{L}
#  ^^^    ^---- the hyphen is after
#  '''--------- a range
# and in this case it is seen as a literal character
```

So, to answer your question, it isn't a bug.

Comment: thanks, it was indeed late.
It was not supposed to be a range;)

Comment: @John: Yes but note that `\p{L}-a` is allowed because the parser reads from the left to the right and deduces that the hyphen is a literal hyphen. idem for `A-Z-a`